# Is there an easy way to check if either all variables are all true together, or all false together?

Tags: boolean

If I have a bunch of variables that either all need to have been initialised or not initialised, like:

```
int handle = -1; // unitialised
void* ptrToSomethingImportant = null;
bool bHasBeenInitialised = false;
```

Then:

```
bool bAreAllUnitialised = handles != -1 && ptrToSomethingImportant != null && bHasBeenInitialised == false;
```

So this tells me if all variables are initialised, but I can't just flip that bool to test if NONE have been initialised. Do I need to rewrite the test again with them all negated?

Comment: In what language?  You're missing a tag.

Comment: @NateEldridge I left a tag out cause I thought it was a more general question applicable to lots of languages. Though I'm using c++

Comment: C++ lets you use the equality operator on boolean expressions, so you can do `bAreAllUnitialized = ((handles == -1) == (ptrToSomethingImportant == null)) && ((ptrToSomethingImportant == null) == bHasBeenInitialized);`.  But I'd want to put a big comment, or wrap it in a function with a more descriptive name.